# The meaning of chrome's devtools-audio function data display

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image]

Where the purple horizontal lines above indicate, network transfer and resource loading, what do they mean.

In addition, what do the upper part, the transparent part and the blue part mean?

Is there any place to explain the meaning of these data in detail? Not explained clearly in Google's official documentation